# ZipUtil Java not zipping same as zip command

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to upload a zip file to a server. When I manually zip the file from the command line using `zip -r output.zip path/to/folder` the upload works fine. However from java when I use `ZipUtil.pack(new File("path/to/folder"), new File("output.zip"));` I get a server error. I'm wondering why this could happen? The zip file I create from java unzips fine, is there a setting or something with ZipUtil that can mimick the exact formatting of the zip command?

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you using the same way to upload the file to the server in both cases? Or are you uploading the Java version programatically?

Comment: Could you please check the compression type used?

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's a generic 500. The server does some processing with the zip that errors out when using ZipUtil. I will ultimately upload programmatically but right now I am testing with the Sublime HTTP Requester (i believe that calls curl under the hood)

Comment: @MJSG I looked through the documentation here https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip not sure how to check or change the compression type... I figured it was a valid zip since it uncompresses fine with unzip

Comment: Have you tried looking at both files with zipinfo? Doing a `cmp`? Do you have access to the server error log?

Comment: are you getting the error when you zip or when you try to upload?

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks for the help, zipinfo pointed me to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZipUtil.pack does not preserve the root directory of the folder by default. Using `ZipUtil.pack(new File("path/to/folder"), new File("output.zip"), true);` you can preserve the root directory, this fixed the issue.